# Lowercase second character in a string php

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have a string that looks like this:

`[House-3-BLUE]`

I want to convert it, using PHP, to:

`[house-3-BLUE]`

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't figure out how to do it after looking at a dozen examples.

Comment: is your string contains brackets also?

Comment: Yes, it has brackets

Answer (score 2):

This would probably work here, and regular expression might not be required:

```
$str = "[House-3-BLUE]";
echo "[" . strtolower(substr($str, 1, 1)) . substr($str, 2);
```

#### Output

```
[house-3-BLUE]
```

#### Advice

It should probably be easier ways to do so, such as [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman)'s advice:

> You should use `lcfirst` then

```
$str = "[House-3-BLUE]";
echo "[" . lcfirst(substr($str, 1));
```

Comment: Sorry, actually, it also puts the word BLUE in lowercase. I would just like to lowercase the letter H.

Comment: You should use [`lcfirst`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php) then

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`substr_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

```
$str = "[House-3-BLUE]";
echo substr_replace($str, strtolower(substr($str, 1, 1)), 1, 1);
```

Try it online: https://3v4l.org/oDoXB

To make the same, but ensure it is Unicode-safe you need to split the string into 3 parts using [`mb_substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) and then concatenate it back into whole string:

```
$str = "House-3-BLUE]";
echo mb_substr($str,0,1) . mb_strtolower(mb_substr($str,1,1)) . mb_substr($str,2);
```

Try it online: https://3v4l.org/NYe0r